# eps file in ubuntu WSL not opening

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

[eThe code is for generating generate p p > t t~ in Madgraph and the get feynman diagrams by display diagrams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9yap.png)
I have tried changing the mg5_configuration to No_Path_Configuration, and there is no change. I am getting the same error again and again. P.S. This is WSL Ubuntu.
Please help. I am new to all these. I tried many things for almost 8 hours, but nothing worked.